# Autocomplete with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have tried out the jQuery autocomplete for multiple values. It works fine but the only problem is that if I enter a word in the textarea then go to the begining of the textarea and enter another word it appends to the end of the text area and not at the CARET position.Could you please help?

Thank You

This is the Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org     

     /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<script  type="text/javascript"> 
  //         document.domain = "toitl.com"; 
  //         alert(document.domain); 
</script> 
<title>Form Field Clear</title> 
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-

  ui.css"  
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
<script type="text/javascript"  src='../../../../libuser/toitldocumentdomain.js'>

    </script> 
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( / \s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" 

         ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {

                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) 

                        ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );

                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( " " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
</script>


  </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="demo">

  <div class="ui-widget"> 
<label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
<textarea id="tags" cols="50" ></textarea>
 </div>

 </div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```